# How to scroll to make a Node within the content of a ScrollPane visible?

Tags: javafx-2

Given that a huge `AnchorPane` with some subnodes is the content of a `ScrollPane`, how can i scroll to make one of the subnodes, that are outside of the current viewport, visible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: code in the next example is more precise than mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23518314/1054140

You need to find a coordinates of this inner node inside `content` and adjust `ScrollPane`'s `vValue` and `hValue` accordingly.

See `ensureVisible()` method in next small app:

```
public class ScrollPaneEnsureVisible extends Application {

    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private static void ensureVisible(ScrollPane pane, Node node) {
        double width = pane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double height = pane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

        double x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX();
        double y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY();

        // scrolling values range from 0 to 1
        pane.setVvalue(y/height);
        pane.setHvalue(x/width);

        // just for usability
        node.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane();
        final Pane content = new Pane();
        root.setContent(content);

        // put 10 buttons at random places with same handler
        final EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                int index = random.nextInt(10);
                System.out.println("Moving to button " + index);
                ensureVisible(root, content.getChildren().get(index));
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Button btn = new Button("next " + i);
            btn.setOnAction(handler);
            content.getChildren().add(btn);
            btn.relocate(2000 * random.nextDouble(), 2000 * random.nextDouble());
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // run once to don't search for a first button manually
        handler.handle(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I created a slightly more elegant version for this case. However , I could only test on the y axis. Hope it helps

```
private static void ensureVisible(ScrollPane scrollPane, Node node) {
    Bounds viewport = scrollPane.getViewportBounds();
    double contentHeight = scrollPane.getContent().localToScene(scrollPane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal()).getHeight();
    double nodeMinY = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal()).getMinY();
    double nodeMaxY = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal()).getMaxY();

    double vValueDelta = 0;
    double vValueCurrent = scrollPane.getVvalue();

    if (nodeMaxY < 0) {
        // currently located above (remember, top left is (0,0))
        vValueDelta = (nodeMinY - viewport.getHeight()) / contentHeight;
    } else if (nodeMinY > viewport.getHeight()) {
        // currently located below
        vValueDelta = (nodeMinY + viewport.getHeight()) / contentHeight;
    }
    scrollPane.setVvalue(vValueCurrent + vValueDelta);
}
```

Comment: What's different about yours?

Comment: Great answer, but I noticed that the if statement needs a fix. When the user has scrolled down the scroll port viewport bounds will have a negative minY value. The if statement should say "if (nodeMaxY < Math.abs(viewport.getMinY())" and the else should say "else if (nodeMinY > viewport.getHeight() + viewport.getMinY())" At least this made it work for me.

Answer (score 4):

To get a perfect snap you need to account for the starting and stop position of the scrollbar.
The viewport starts at half viewport from 0(Bounds scollpane) and stops a half viewport from max Bound.
[bounds vs viewport picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r12cO.png)

so : 
node Y below a half viewport ->setVvalue to  0
node Y above maxheigh-half viewport -> set value to 1

and between that we need to calculate the total height -1viewport(half start half at end  ) and the node y - half viewport.
then (node y - half viewport) / (total height -1viewport)

```
                double heightViewPort = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
                double heightScrollPane = scrollPane.getContent().getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
                double y = Label.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY();
                if (y<(heightViewPort/2)){
                    scrollPane.setVvalue(0);
                    // below 0 of scrollpane

                }else if ((y>=(heightViewPort/2))&(y<=(heightScrollPane-heightViewPort/2))){
                   // between 0 and 1 of scrollpane
                    scrollPane.setVvalue((y-(heightViewPort/2))/(heightScrollPane-heightViewPort));
                }
                else if(y>= (heightScrollPane-(heightViewPort/2))){
                    // above 1 of scrollpane
                    scrollPane.setVvalue(1);

                }
```