# JavaFX: textArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE) not always works

Tags: java, javafx

This is the piece of my code.

```
textArea.setText(someNewText)
textArea.positionCaret(textArea.getText().length());
textArea.setEditable(true);
textArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

I use `textArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE)` to scroll textarea to the bottom (solution I found in internet). It works, but not always. I've noted that it can not work only when vertical scroll bar is not visible before calling this code and visible after the code was executed. When vertical scroll bar is visible before calling this code then scrolling to the bottom works always. How to fix it? Maybe I should make vertical scroll bar always visible? If yes, then how - I didn't find the solution.

**EDIT:**
This is the sample code:

```
public class JavaFxApp1 extends Application{

    private TextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button button=new Button("Press here");
        textArea=new TextArea();
        VBox vbox = new VBox(button,textArea);
        button.setOnAction((event)->{
            textArea.appendText("###This is a very long string:some text some text some text some text some"
                    + " text some text some text some text some text some text"
                    + " text some text some text some text some text some text"
                    + " text some text some text some text some text some text .\n");
            textArea.selectEnd();
            textArea.deselect();
            textArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        });
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);
        textArea.setStyle("-fx-font-size:14px;-fx-focus-color: transparent;-fx-font-family: monospace;");
        Scene scene=new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setTitle("SomeTitle");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMinHeight(400);
        stage.setMinWidth(800);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This is the result when I pressed button 4 times:
[image]
As you see it didn't scroll to the bottom. After I press button again (the fifth time) I have the following result:
[image]
Now, as you see it was scrolled to the bottom. 
I tried to add:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = (ScrollPane) textArea.lookup(".scroll-pane");  
scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
```

to make scrollbar visible always - it is visible but after 4 times anyway doesn't scroll to the bottom.

How to fix it?

Comment: This is a bug, so I opened a bug report. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. See the following link https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189732

Answer (score 1):

if you want to scroll to the Top your code will be this way

```
ta.selectHome();
ta.deselect();
```

if you want to scroll to the Bottom your code will be this way

```
ta.selectEnd();
ta.deselect();
```

now let the `TextArea` worry about its visible areas

**edit**

maybe i didnt get your requirement, cause honestly this is the first time i have seen that method so to give an answer based on your hypothesis

> Maybe I should make vertical scroll bar always visible? If yes, then how

well thats easy `TextArea` uses `ScrollPane`, when there is a visible scroll
this line `TextArea.getChildrenUnmodifiable().size();` will check out to be 1, so you fish it out when you create your `TextArea`

```
TextArea.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Node>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.
            Change<? extends Node> c) {
            while(c.next()){
                if(c.wasAdded()){
                    for(Node n : TextArea.getChildrenUnmodifiable()){
                        if(n.getClass().isAssignableFrom(ScrollPane.class)){
                            //just trying to be cool here ^^
                            ScrollPane sp = (ScrollPane) n;
                            sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

actually you can keep a reference to the `ScrollPane` and anytime you want to scroll to the bottom `ScrollPane.setVvalue(1.0);` to the top `ScrollPane.setVvalue(0.0);` etc etc.

you can get the value with `ScrollPane.getVvalue()`.

Comment: Thank you for ideas, but it didn't help. See my edit.

Comment: @JimJim2000 remove this line bro `textArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: I tried both with this line and without it - the same result.

Comment: @JimJim2000 i just tried it worked on my system without it.

Comment: By the way, if you find this question interesting you can upvote it to draw people attention.

Comment: no problem, try this `textArea.setPadding(new Insets(10));` it will solve your problem, the reason why is this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840513/javafx-scrollpane-programmatically-moving-the-viewport-centering-content) you can manually the calcs if you like on the ScrollPane @JimJim2000