# How to change the view port in javafx?

Tags: javafx, viewport

I have created a screen for my GUI like this . [image]

Now after the program starts  i just want to show the user FirstBtn like this:[image]

and after the button is clicked the screen moves in the direction of the arrow in the picture and goes to the secondBtn [image]

now how should i move the screen and change the view port.

Comment: Do you wish to center the second button in the viewport after the first button is clicked? Perhaps this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837592/how-to-scroll-to-make-a-node-within-the-content-of-a-scrollpane-visible) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use different scenes for the same stage.

```
 primayStage.setScene(yourScene1);
```

and same when needed for yourScene2

```
primayStage.setScene(yourScene2);
```